# How to fix ElasticSearch conflicts on the same key when two process writing at the same time

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple processes to write data to ES at the same time, also two processes may write the same key with different values at the same time, it caused the exception as following:

```
"error" : "VersionConflictEngineException[[website][2] [blog][1]:
             version conflict, current [2], provided [1]]",
"status" : 409
```

How could I fix the above problem please, since I have to keep multiple processes.

Comment: I'm guessing that you tried the obvious solution of doing a get by id just before doing the insert/update ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`VersionConflictEngineException` is thrown to prevent data loss. Every document in elasticsearch has a `_version` number that is incremented whenever a document is changed.

When you query a doc from ES, the response also includes the version of that doc. When you update the same doc and provide a version, then a document with the same version is expected to be already existing in the index.

If the current version is greater than the one in the update request, What we would get now is a conflict, with the HTTP error code of 409 and `VersionConflictEngineException`

In your current scenario,

> version conflict, current [2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html), provided [1](https://www.elastic.co/blog/versioning)

The current version in ES is 2 whereas in your request is 1 which means some other thread has already modified the doc and your change is trying overwrite the doc.

In case of VersionConflictEngineException, you should re-fetch the doc and try to update again with the latest updated version.

Whether or not to use the [versioning](https://www.elastic.co/blog/versioning) / [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html), depends on the application. If you can live with data-loss, you may avoid passing version in the update request.

Comment: Hey Rahul, I am not even providing version while updating doc, but I still get this exception. Not sure why, but I think the reason might, I have refresh_interval=30s. and if i update it before that then it throws version conflict. Do u think this could be the reason?

Comment: Hey hi, it automatically create a version and if two queries run in parallel there is conflict. I am currently looking for a solution other than a rety on conflict infinty ...

Comment: Yes but the assumption I mentioned is correct?. I changes refresh interval from 30s to 1s now, and no version conflict since then.

Comment: It doesnt thrown in my case, I get ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=version_conflict_engine_exception, reason=[_doc][2968265]: version conflict, current version [8] is different than the one provided [7], but this exception is not even a child of VersionConflictEngineException.

Answer (score 13):

The ES provides the ability to use the [retry_on_conflict](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) query parameter.

> Specify how many times should the operation be retried when a conflict occurs. Default: 0.

If you have several parallel scripts that can simultaneously work with the same document, you can use this parameter.

For example:
You have an index for tweets. And 5 processes that will work with this index. It is possible that all 5 scripts will work with the same document (some tweet). In this case, you can use the `...&retry_on_conflict=6` parameter. Why 6? 5 processes + 1 (plus some legroom). Thus, the ES will try to re-update the document up to 6 times if conflicts occur.

Answer (score 4):

You could also plan for this by using the elastic search external versioning system and maintain the document versions manually as stated below

[image]

Comment: Please do not screenshot documentation.  While this may answer the question, providing the answer in text-form regarding why and/or how this answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and the reason was that I was running the consumer (the app) on a terminal command, and at the same time I was also running the consumer (the app) on the debugger, so the running code was trying to execute an elasticsearch query two times simultaneously and the conflict was occurred. So I terminated one of them (the debugger) and executed the code only on my terminal and the error was gone.
**So, make sure you are not running the code from more than one instance.**