# Version conflicts in update_by_query - how with only a single writer?

Tags: elasticsearch

We're in the middle of trying to take an ES index live with about ~2M documents. We have 1 shard (I know, I got that wrong) and the refresh rate is 10 seconds.

In the middle of a large re-index (which has taken many hours) I keep seeing errors such as this in the logs:

```
2019-08-13|11:25:32.6516|1|Warn|Conflict[0]:Doc cv.-.4439064; cause: [_doc][cv.-.4439064]: version conflict, current version [3] is different than the one provided [2]
Conflict[1]:Doc cv.-.4439862; cause: [_doc][cv.-.4439862]: version conflict, current version [3] is different than the one provided [2]
Conflict[2]:Doc cv.-.4440790; cause: [_doc][cv.-.4440790]: version conflict, current version [3] is different than the one provided [2]
Conflict[3]:Doc cv.-.4441758; cause: [_doc][cv.-.4441758]: version conflict, current version [3] is different than the one provided [2]
```

I coded to sleep for 10 seconds then retry up to 3 times so the operation goes through eventually. But it fails a *second* time before going through, even though I've backed off for the refresh rate.

The error above is nearly always followed by a repeat involving the same docs:

```
2019-08-13|11:25:44.1724|1|Warn|Conflict[0]:Doc cv.-.4439064; cause: [_doc][cv.-.4439064]: version conflict, current version [4] is different than the one provided [3]
Conflict[1]:Doc cv.-.4439862; cause: [_doc][cv.-.4439862]: version conflict, current version [4] is different than the one provided [3]
Conflict[2]:Doc cv.-.4440790; cause: [_doc][cv.-.4440790]: version conflict, current version [4] is different than the one provided [3]
Conflict[3]:Doc cv.-.4441758; cause: [_doc][cv.-.4441758]: version conflict, current version [4] is different than the one provided [3]
```

Given that:

1. when a re-index is underway for a specific customer I queue up
   updates for that customer and don't process them until the re-index is finished
2. there is only 1 writer - I deliberately went for the simple case for our
   first deployment

Why does this happen at all?

And why does it take *twice* the refresh rate before the update succeeds?

I am pretty sure that one of the reasons this operation has been so slow (about 48 hours) is because of this.

Comment: May I ask you how do you do the "re-index"? Is it a custom script?

Comment: It's a multi-tenant system so there are docs there for about 150 customers. When a re-index starts for a customer we delete all their docs and then re-add. Instructions are posted on SQS. Along with re-index messages there are normal deltas for other customers (the update by queries). Updates for a customer being re-indexed are shunted into a temp q and handled once the re-index is finished. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I think there are 2 possible explanations.
1) A `DELETE` on a document X actually happens after re-adding same document X due to [optimistic concurrency control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html). 
2) there is a bug and update-by-query actually updates the docs that are re-indexed. 
Since this is far from a useful answer, I am posting it as a comment. I would recommend to check how `version` is sent in delete/update queries.

Comment: Also this answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188917/how-to-fix-elasticsearch-conflicts-on-the-same-key-when-two-process-writing-at-t

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev Many thanks for taking the time to respond. I'll look into what you suggest.

Comment: This may sound foolish, want to confirm, are you using _update_by_query to re-index? What params are passed during that?

Comment: @User3518958 Nope, it doesn't sound foolish. The update_by_query commands are for slight changes in the state of a doc. So a user on our main system changes the state of 1 field, this gets posted to the backend which issues an update_by_query. Reindexes start with a huge delete and then we just re-add everything. I did discover that our system was posting extra updates which massively exacerbated the issue, but even with that fixed I'm still seeing it. If I ever find a definitive reason I'll post it but it's looking like a "1 symptom; several causes" bug. Thanks for the response.